# What is the high level idea why trapdoor is used for digital signature?

Tags: trapdoor

What is the high level  idea why trapdoor is used for digital signature?
Are there any digital signature schemes without trapdoor?

Comment: Hash based signature schemes don't rely on trapdoor functions